How to show on the user page fields from a referenced entity?
I have added entity reference fields for my users, that reference other users.  I have a "Father" entity reference field for example so a user can choose that another user is their father (to show family relationships).  This works great and links to the user name of the person that is the person's father (or mother or child).  What I would like to do is show the name of the person that is their father/mother/child instead of the user name (so basically pull a field from the referenced entity instead of the referenced title/username).
Is there a way to do that?  Is it something I would have to do in the twig template?  Or maybe replace the user page with a (more configurable) view instead?
Thanks to anyone who can help!  (PS this is Drupal 9)
